# How can I Order By a column I don't want displayed in the output?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to generate a query to display specific data in specific grouping and order.
The only issue I have is that, to get the proper Order of the data in the columns I need to order it by a column that I have not SELECTED and do not want displayed.

So When I try to ORDER BY that column I get the error:

> *"Column ** is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."*

Is there a syntax that will allow me to do this?
Here's the query I'm working with:

```sql
select Pr.EmployeeNo as EmpNo, EmployeeFName as EmpFName, EmployeeLName as EmpLName,
ProjectName, ProjectStartDate as ProjStartDate, JobName as Job, JobRate, HoursWorked as Hours
from Employee as Em join ProjEmp as Pr on Em.EmployeeNo = Pr.EmployeeNo
                    join Project as Pt on Pr.ProjectID = Pt.ProjectID
                    join Job as Jb on Em.JobID = Jb.JobID
Group by Pr.EmployeeNo, EmployeeFName, EmployeeLName, ProjectName, ProjectStartDate, JobName, JobRate, HoursWorked
```

Comment: which is proper order you have no order by in your query

Comment: @nbk. The Order BY wasn't in the example because the column I needed to order by was not in the Select or GROUP BY. I realized I can Order By the column if I add it to the GROUP BY.

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT about 4 minutes after posting the question, and I Answered it below. Thank you for your input however. I Just can't mark my own answer as the answer for two days... Perhaps a mod could do that more quickly?

Comment: @ArthwysIronhand - moderators can't mark answers as accepted. Have you evaluated whether the other answer posted answers the question and should be selected as the accepted answer anyway? It was posted before yours and appears more comprehensive on first glance so why do you specifically want to select your one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop and read the *full error* again. It tells you **exactly** what's going on. Hint: the problem is not that it's missing from the `SELECT` clause. There's no reason you can't do this:

```
SELECT ColumnA
FROM [Table1]
ORDER BY ColumnB
```

The problem is you have a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
Column is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not
 contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

And this makes sense. Say you have this table:

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 9 |
| 2 | 6 | 7 |
| 2 | 8 | 5 |

And then try to run this query:

```
SELECT ColumnA, MAX(ColumnB)
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY ColumnA
ORDER BY ColumnC
```

This query tries to ORDER BY ColumnC, but **there's more than one value for ColumnC in each group!** We have two groups on ColumnA: `1` and `2`. Group `1` has two "C" values: `3` and `9`. Group `2` also has two "C" values: `7` and `5`. Depending on which rows is selected, you could end up with **different orders**.

ColumnA, though, is okay, because it's part of the `GROUP BY` expression. That means we know what value to use. `MAX(ColumnB)` is also okay, because `MAX()` is an aggregate function. It tells us which value from the group to use in a deterministic way. But **the ColumnC reference is ambiguous(!)**, and so is not allowed.

So in the SQL from the question, you are free to use any of these columns for the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
Pr.EmployeeNo, EmployeeFName, EmployeeLName, ProjectName, ProjectStartDate, JobName, JobRate, HoursWorked
```

If you want to use a different column, you must either alter the grouping (and think carefully on the consequences) or use an aggregate function on the column group.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed response. I was writing my own anwser when you posted this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The answer was to add the column to the GROUP BY.
Because I didn't SELECT the column, it won't display. BUT GROUPing BY the column allows me to ORDER BY it, and it won't display because it wasn't actually SELECTED.

Sorry for the trouble.